# My JList model method gives me an error

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jlist

I had a lecture today and I literally wrote what the teacher did, but the code just gives me an error saying:

```
java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted javax.swing.ListSelectionModel
```

This is the code that is faulty:

```
JList<String> list = new JList<>(listModel);
/*
...
*/
list.setSelectionModel(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand? The `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION` variable returns an "int" value. The `setSelectionModel(...)` method expects a `ListSelectionModel`. This is basic Java.  Read the API for more information about the method when you have a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your teacher wrote:

```
JList<String> list = new JList<>(listModel);
/*
...
*/
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

//note how the methods name is supposed to end with Mode, not Model
```